Contractibility of Comb Space to (0,0)
I'm wondering if the following proof is correct and if not where i lack the understanding.
Let $X$ be the comb space, that is, the compact subset of $R^2$ consisting of the horizontal interval $\{(x,0):0\leq x\leq 1\}$ and the closed vertical intervals of unit length with lower endpoints at $(0,0)$ and $(0,1/n), 1\leq n<\infty.$ Show that $X$ is contractible to $(0,0)$ with $(0,0)$ held fixed.
Proof: We create a path $\alpha$ between the n'th tooth at  $x_n=({1\over {n}},1)$ and $x_1=({1\over {n}},0)$ then the path $\beta$ from $x_1=({1\over {n}}, 0)$ to $x_0=(0,0).$ We have $$\gamma_t(s,n)=\begin{cases}
   \alpha(2ns), & 0\leq s\leq {1\over {2n}}\\
            \beta(2ns-1), & {1\over {2n}}\leq s\leq 1
   \end{cases}
$$
which works for the convex paths $$\alpha_t=(1-t)x_1+tx, \hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq t\leq 1$$
$$\beta_t=(1-t)x_0+tx, \hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq t\leq 1$$
since
$$\alpha_0(x)=F(x,0)=x_1$$
$$\alpha_1(x)=F(x,1)=x$$
$$\alpha_t(x_1)=F(x,t)=x_1$$
we have that the space of the paths $\alpha$ is contractible to the point $x_1.$
And since
$$\beta_0(x)=F(x,t)=x_0$$
$$\beta_1(x)=F(x,t)=x$$
$$\beta_t(x_0)=F(x_0,t)=x_0$$
the space of the paths $\beta$ is contractible to the point $x_0$ and thus $\gamma_t(s,n)$ is contractible to $x_0.$
